# Setting an HTML class to a JSP List Length

Tags: html, class, jsp, dynamic, server-side

I have a JSP List labelled ${contentList} that contains product information (product image, name, price, etc.)

I am populating a HTML table with this data via JSP, what I would like to do set the class of the initial table row with the number of items in the contentList.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<c:forEach items="${contentList.length}" var="content" varStatus="status3">
     <tr class="">
        <td>
          <a href="<bean:write name="content" property="hyperlink"/>">
            <img src="<bean: write name="content" property="imagePath"/>">
            <h2><bean:write name="content" property="title"/></h2>
            <h3><bean:write name="content" property="price"/></h3>
          </a>
        </td>
     </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I think I'm missing some syntax in the class="${contentList.length}" that is causing an error, no matter the language, syntax has ALWAYS been my mortal enemy. I'm relatively new to JSP, so any assitance to help me along would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
class="${fn:length(contentList)}"
```